# Design table in itexthelper pdf in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I want to design table in as shown in the image. Please help me.
Please look at the code below.

[image]

```
            PdfPTable InfoTable = new PdfPTable(4);
        InfoTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;
        InfoTable.SpacingAfter = 10.5f;

        PdfPCell InfoCellT1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Head 1", getFont(12, strWebPath)));
        InfoCellT1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        InfoCellT1.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
        InfoCellT1.Padding = 2f;
        PdfPCell InfoCellT2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Head 2", getFont(12, strWebPath)));
        InfoCellT2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        InfoCellT2.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
        InfoCellT2.Padding = 2f;
        PdfPCell InfoCellT3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Head 3", getFont(12, strWebPath)));
        InfoCellT3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        InfoCellT3.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
        InfoCellT3.Padding = 2f;
        PdfPCell InfoCellT4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Head 4", getFont(12, strWebPath)));
        InfoCellT4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        InfoCellT4.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
        InfoCellT4.Padding = 2f;

        InfoTable.AddCell(InfoCellT1);
        InfoTable.AddCell(InfoCellT2);
        InfoTable.AddCell(InfoCellT3);
        InfoTable.AddCell(InfoCellT4);
        
        
         PdfPCell Info1Cell1 = new PdfPCell();

        Info1Cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1", getFont(3, strWebPath)));
        Info1Cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        Info1Cell1.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
        Info1Cell1.Padding = 1f;
        PdfPCell Info1Cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("first", getFont(3, strWebPath)));
        Info1Cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        Info1Cell2.Padding = 4f;
        PdfPCell Info1Cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("part 1 ", getFont(3, strWebPath)));
        Info1Cell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        Info1Cell3.Padding = 1.5f;
        PdfPCell Info1Cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1 dot 1" + "\n2 dot 2" + "\n2 dot 2" + "\n3 dot 3", getFont(3, strWebPath)));
        Info1Cell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        Info1Cell4.Padding = 5f;
        
        InfoTable.AddCell(Info1Cell1);
        InfoTable.AddCell(Info1Cell2);
        InfoTable.AddCell(Info1Cell3);
        InfoTable.AddCell(Info1Cell4);
```

So far, the code shown above has been tried. So how can I achieve the table shown in the image?

Comment: This is not a question.  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: The only information you seem to be needing is that there is a `PdfPCell` property `Rowspan` that indicates how many rows a given cell shall span.